# Flutter Bluetooth Serial library does not work on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I run the example on iOS it does not work:

https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial

I got this :

```
======== Exception caught by services library==============================================
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel flutter_bluetooth_serial/state:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel flutter_bluetooth_serial/state)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:545:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin supports the legacy RFCOMM profile.  This profile is not available to apps on iOS.

This plugin cannot work with iOS (Nor can any plugin that uses the RFCOMM profile).

Comment: is there any other plugins available for IOS?

Comment: For BLE? Probably. For serial Bluetooth, no, because apps on iOS cannot access the serial port protocol or any legacy Bluetooth protocol,