# Is there any plugin available for Flutter Bluetooth serial communication for IOS and Android

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I am new to flutter.
I came across flutter_bluetooth_serial it works only for android  ..please suggest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Bluetooth Serial library does not work on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67237519/flutter-bluetooth-serial-library-does-not-work-on-ios)

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion could be to use Android ;-) Howsoever, flutter_bluetooth_serial implementation uses Classical Bluetooth and here we enter the land of Apples [MFI](https://mfi.apple.com/) (Made for iPhone/iPod/iPad) licensing programme . This is the reason for the lack of support in libraries like flutter.

I suggest using another interface with fewer restrictions, for example Bluetooth LE.

Comment: but with Bluetooth LE plugins like flutter_blue we can not have serial communication.using ble we can read/write with Bluetooth characteristics only

Comment: Also with Bluetooth LE you can get such a UART functionality. There are some companies/organisations that have implemented a corresponding service/profile. Example:
https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v15.0.0%2Fble_sdk_app_nus_eval.html